# Getting JSON Response with volley- Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-volley, json, jsonobjectrequest

I am working on an android project for my class.

I have to get `JsonObject` response from two urls.

The first one is `get_token`, where I will get a json response of token number when I parse a valid username and password into the url.
The second one is `get_message` method where I will get a secret message with the token generated from `get_token`. I was able to successfully get a token, but I am stuck at getting the secret message.
How do I pass the token?

Here is the code for my main activity:

```
private String urlJsonObj = "http://sfsuswe.com/413/get_token/?username=sahithiv&password=912549149";

private String urlJsonObj1="http://sfsuswe.com/413/get_message/?token=";

private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Button btnMakeObjectRequest;

ProgressDialog pDialog;

private TextView txtResponse;

private String jsonResponse;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

btnMakeObjectRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnObjRequest);

txtResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);

txtResponse.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");

pDialog.setCancelable(false);

btnMakeObjectRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

makeJsonObjectRequest();

}

});

}

/**

* Method to make json object request where json response starts wtih {

* */

private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {

showpDialog();

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,

urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

@Override

public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

try {

// Parsing json object response

// response will be a json object

String token = response.getString("token");

jsonResponse = "\n\n\n";

jsonResponse += "token:" + token + "\n\n\n\n";

txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

} catch (JSONException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

"Error: " + e.getMessage(),

Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

hidepDialog();

}

}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

@Override

public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

// hide the progress dialog

hidepDialog();

}

});

AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

}

private void showpDialog() {

if (!pDialog.isShowing())

pDialog.show();

}

private void hidepDialog() {

if (pDialog.isShowing())

pDialog.dismiss();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass **Token** appended with **Next** url.

```
String token = response.getString("token");
```

For **Next** url response:

```
String nextUrl = urlJsonObj1+token;

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,

nextUrl, null, new Response.Listener() {

@Override

public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

Log.d(TAG+"Final Response", response.toString());

}

AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

**Output** would be:

```
{
    "description": "CSC 413.02 Spring 2016 Project 2 Secret Message",
    "message": "On the neighboring shore the fires from the foundry chimneys burning high and glaringly into the night,"
}
```

Hope this will heelp you.

Comment: Thank You for the response. It makes sense.I will try to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didnt read the question & code correctly.May be a wrong answer

I guess you are getting String token as null when outside the request.

I had a same issue when I wanted to use response outside the vollley request.

Create a separate class with

```
  class store_response{
private static String token;
public static void set_token(String token_separated_from_response)
//to store the token
{
token=token_separated_from_response;
}

//for retrieving token
public static void get_token()
{
return token;
}
}
```

So when storing a response just call 
store_response.set_token(token_extracted_from_response);

And for retrieving outside the volley request.
String token=store_response.get_token();

I'm posting this from mobile so sorry for not typing in code form.

Answer (score -1):

You can solved this problem very simply....

1. Create two method one for get_token  two for get_message
2. First time call first method when you get response successfully then call your 2nd method by pass your token as parameter. I check your api response and i think this is best solution for u. thanks